# piping to two php scripts in qmail

Tags: email

I have a php script which gets the received emails with piping method. This is set in /var/qmail/mailnames/mydomain.com/.qmail-default as:

```
|/path/to/my/script.php
```

I want to pipe the received email to two different php scripts. Is this possible?

Is it possible to set two pipes in /var/qmail/mailnames/mydomain.com/.qmail-default ?

```
|/path/to/my/script_1.php
|/path/to/my/script_2.php
```

Do you have any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just tested it and you need to enter multiple pipes on multiple lines.